# Development in Java inside Anylogic - Trying acess parametrs of agents

Tags: java, anylogic

I created a simulation using an Anylogic package. The traffic light simulation package. It turns out that now I need to use this simulation for an algorithm to generate random numbers before the start of each simulation of traffic light times.

I am not able to access the attributes of the agents that create within the simulation. I need to access the parameters of the traffic lights that I put in the model so that through the code in Java I can change these values ​​according to the results of the simulation. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a public (!) function on the parent class of your package (likely `main`) that changes the parameter value using a given argument.

After compiling into a jar file, you will have access to that function and can set the param.

You might also try to call an auto-generated function `set_myParam(..)` if your param is called `myParam`. AnyLogic auto-generates such setters. Depends on how the package was created

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a beginner in anylogic. I created the simulation but I don't have much knowledge, because it is a very large and powerful tool. I added two images to the original question. Would I have to create this class you said in the place where I put it in the first image? And how would I use it within the code in the second image? Thanks for your help.

Comment: For example, I have an agent that is from a CarSource block, the name of that agent is carSource_Street_20. At the end of each simulation I would have to take the number of vehicles that arrived at this agent and analyze it. How do I get inside my Java class to get this parameter?